# TortoiseSVN on local PC with existing projects

Tags: svn, tortoise-svn

I have a few existing coding projects, in scattered directories and would like to bring them under version control on my local PC.

I tried following [the instructions](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-repository.html#tsvn-repository-create-tortoisesvn), but couldn't see how to add files.

- Should/must I have a single repository, or should/can I have one for each project? Or is it a mtter of personl preference?
- The code for my current project is in `f:\DropBox\programs\Xampp\htdocs\api` and I don't want to move it. Where should my repository be?

I am sure this is all very simple, but until now I have only used SVN at work and soemone else had set up the repository.

Anythign else I should know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Preface**

You **must** to read docs, at least SVN Book, in order to have clean vision "what", "why", "when" - I'm too lazy to cite you full chapters from it. It also eliminate a lot of novice questions. But, as starting point, I'll answer

1. You can select and use any repository layout (SVN Book note it specially): SVN doesn't have any restrictions on it - it's a matter of taster and habits, some devs prefer "repository per project" (more trees under control, more complex backups, easier management of every repo), some prefer multi-projects monilithic repo (inversed notes of previous choice)
2. You must understand and see differences between "repository", "working copy", "exported tree" entities. For your case:

   - Working Copy (or even exported tree) inside dropbox-controlled directory is **The Bad Idea (tm)** (just trust me here blindly)
   - You can place repository locally when you want, current site can be converted into Working Copy or Working Copy can be independent additional object and site is target of export operations (performed automatically with hooks or on demand) - you'll find *your way*